# A word for something that shows whether something is true or false?

Tags: word-request

I am not thinking of a word like experiment, but something more general if it's possible. I think there was a word like that, but I don't remember what it was.

Comment: Acid test, proof, verification, litmus test, touchstone, check, trial. (Words from google search for synonyms of *acid test*.)

Comment: And validation and corroboration (more synonym search results).

Comment: Validity? How do you plan on using this word? Give us a sample sentence.